# Compare method for type int

Tags: c#, search, int, compare, contain

I want to do the following but the only issue is that my input query is int not string and also I am searching from my RoomID which is also an integer and not a string. Let me simplify it, instead of _context.Customers.Name, I am comparing from _context.Room.Id which is an int type. This is an obligation and I have to do this. Guys ignore the .Select(Mapper.Map<>) Method, the primary focus is the int problem. I'd appreciate some help.
[image]

Comment: `bool result = source.ToString.Contains(toFind.ToString());`?

Comment: try using a regex?

Comment: As an instructor once told me, "If you're not doing math on them, they aren't numbers" (Don't use ints if you want strings)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to solve it is to convert the integers to string and do a contain.

Ex.

```
var needle = 234;
var haystack = 79234826;
var contains = haystack.ToString().Contains(needle.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to search as if both `int`s are `string`s, just let them be `string`s:

```
    int source = 79234826;
    int toFind = 234;

    bool found = source.ToString().Contains(toFind.ToString());
```

Comment: you are missing ()

Comment: @Sajeetharan: I'm sorry for the typo; Thank you for the pointing out.